# Zend config exception in application.ini in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following configuration in application.ini

```
[www.domain.com : default]
environment = production
```

It works fine with www but not without www. When I try without www then I get the following error message.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Section 'domain.com' cannot be found....in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/public/application/configs/application.ini'
```

Now I am bit confused if this is causing because of dns settings or virtual hosts file.

In virtual host configuration file contains the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        ErrorLog /home/user/public_html/domain.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /home/user/public_html/domain.com/log/access.log combined
        DocumentRoot "/home/user/public_html/domain.com/public/web"
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
                <Directory "/home/user/public_html/domain.com/public/web">
                        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                        DirectoryIndex index.php
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please suggest. Any help if highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to DNS or your vhost. It's an INI issue. As far as ZF is concerned, there is no `domain.com` section of application.ini. There's just a `www.domain.com` section. In this particular case since you only have one setting to be inherited, here is a simple solution...

```
[www.domain.com : default]
environment = production

[domain.com : default]
environment = production
```

Comment: In my case it only works in this way [default] variables... then [domain.com : www.domain.com] and next I had to add [www.domain.com : default] environment = production

Comment: No problem, Raj. I still don't understand how your solution doesn't result in an error, but the important thing is that it's working for you.